# Parity synced at not existing block 4839212

Tags: blockchain, parity, synchronization, blocks, hash

I have problem with parity, cant get synchronization in archive mode to end,
anything, changing arguments, max-, min-, snapshot-peers, parity verisions do not help.
I have blockchain in archive mode synced to
 block: 4839212 
with hash:
0xf418b3b2fbadccab0a6e7009792906006f66e17356c7640e874def344933e847

This block does not exist according etherscan.io, how can i get synchronization to end???

Comment: What version are you using? What is the commandline used to launch parity?

Comment: Parity  v 2.4.5
        
args: ["-d",
               "/ethereum-data",
               "--no-warp", "--tracing", "on", "--pruning", "archive",
               "--jsonrpc-hosts", "all",
               "--jsonrpc-interface", "all",
               "--no-serve-light",
               "--max-peers",
               "250",
               "--min-peers",
               "10",
               "--mode",
               "active",
               "--cache-size",
               "4096",
               "--db-compaction",
               "hdd",
               "--allow-ips=public", "--no-discovery"]

Comment: But I tested also different settings, all similar to this upper.

Comment: Synchronization was started on older parity version